# Accessing Component inside a component

Tags: aem

I have created a page which is of type `cq:page`. I have a component under the `jcr:content` node of this page as `nt:unstructured` type and points to the component location in apps.

I have hardcoded a component inside this component. Now, I'm unable to access the nodes in the second component. I need to set properties of the nodes (in the second component) using the ResourceResolver — how do I access the nodes in the second component?

Comment: What have you tried, what was the outcome & how does it differ to what you expected to happen. Also let us know what errors you're seeing, if any.

Comment: i'm not sure how to start this one. so just keep on thinking and banging my head for a long time.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, though I think you need to break down the problem to a discreet task that's not happening as you expect — Frankly, without adding a specific problem that you're struggling with, along with some sample code, it comes across like you're asking people to write the code for you, which will likely get you a negative response on the site. Have you read the documentation related to Sling/JCR about accessing child nodes/resources? What is it in particular that you have a problem with?

Comment: to access a particular node, we need to have a relative path/absolute path. In my particular case, since i'm using component inside a component, i'm unable to get the path of the second component. i'm new to cq. so correct me if i'm wrong..

Comment: if you hardcoded a nested component, you can get the node of the child via sling or jcr api:
Sling: resource.getChild(relPath)
JCR: node.getNode(relPath)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're hard-coding component B inside of component A, you can also statically define its path relative to A.

Presumably, you're using [`<cq:include>`](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/taglib.html#%3Ccq:include%3E) to embed component B inside of component A.
Two of its possible attributes are the `path` and `resourceType`. Path in this case is the relative path that the included component will have when created.

So if the JSP for component A contains:

```
<!--Some component A content here -->

<cq:include path="inner" resourceType="myProject/components/content/componentB"/>

<!-- Some more component A content -->
```

Any time a node with a resource type of "componentA" is created, it will create a child node with a relative path to component A of "inner" (with a resource type of `componentB`).

I.e. if the outer component in your case is at `/content/mysite/mypage/jcr:content/componentA`, then the inner component will be at `/content/mysite/mypage/jcr:content/componentA/inner`, given the code above.